# Saving file to arraylist and writing back to file; Android

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to open a text file and and save each line as the contents of an arraylist. Once this has been completed I would like to save it back to a file. I have been running into errors for so long and have tried numerous techniques. I found that for some reason, the files themselves are not being created. It may just be a simple error I'm overlooking but if you could provide any help I will be thankful.

Here's the code:

```
public void addToFile(){

File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/appName/savedlocations");
root.mkdirs();
File fileName = new File(root, "locationslatitude.txt");
File fileName2 = new File(root, "locationslongitude.txt");

String file = fileName.toString();
String file2 = fileName2.toString();

String theContent = Double.toString(currLatitude);
String theContent2 = Double.toString(currLongitude);

s = new Scanner(file);
    while (s.hasNext()){
        fileList.add(s.next());
    }
    s.close();
    fileList.add(theContent);



    s2 = new Scanner(file2);
    while (s2.hasNext()){
        fileList2.add(s2.next());
    }
    s2.close();
    fileList2.add(theContent2);


try {//works for latitude file
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 
        for(String str: fileList) { 
          writer.write(str);
          writer.write("\r\n");
        }
        writer.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException error) {
          //do something if an IOException occurs.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot Save Back To A File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
//save the arraylist back to its appropriate file
    try {//works for longitude file
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file2); 
        for(String str2: fileList2) { 
          writer.write(str2);
          writer.write("\r\n");
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException error) {
      //do something if an IOException occurs.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot Save Back To A File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I believe I found the answer to the problem and I wanted to post it back on here so if anyone else faces the same problem this might help them.

The problem was that it wasn't creating the file. The directory was created using "root.mkdirs();". However, the files were not created and I was trying to read from non-existing files. This is what I believe caused the error. So, in order to fix this problem I altered the code to this:

```
  try{

        s = new Scanner(fileName);
        while (s.hasNext()){
            fileList.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
                fileList.add(theContent);

}catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    try{
        fileName.createNewFile();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hit IOException for file one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

try{  
        s2 = new Scanner(fileName2);
        while (s2.hasNext()){
            fileList2.add(s2.next());
        }
        s2.close();
                fileList2.add(theContent2);
}catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    try{
        fileName2.createNewFile();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hit IOException for file two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This was the only piece of code I had to alter. The code which saved back to the file worked. I hope this will be of use to someone and thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Didn't already ask this same question? Can you get a stack trace of the error that happens and post that?

Comment: You should post the errors or at least write them out.  Do "Cannot Save Back To A File : " + error.getMessage() or . It should also be in logview.

Comment: Actually if you don't post error messages good chance people will dock points from the question.  So please do that now.

Comment: Remember this.  The piece of this code that I would be most critical of is that you are not logging the error message.  Please log the error message.  No reason to just tell yourself you have some error without reporting the specifics of the error message

Comment: I am running the app on my phone and in order to use the sd card, I must disconnect it from the computer, which, makes it a little harder to log. However, I will try and run it on the emulator and post the log file. Hopefully, that will help lead to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works in my project. You can use it to save ArrayList contents to text file. Make sure that the directory is created beforehand. Just iterate through your list and use println method to write it to txt file.

```
FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/appName/savedlocations/nameoftextfile.txt");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);
out.println("PRINT LINES WITH ME");
out.print("NOT NECCESSARILY A NEW LINE");
out.close(); // at the very end
```

Do not forget to catch IOException.

Comment: I still seem to run into the same problem. I'm very confused as to why. I will try and post the log files as soon as possible that way it might be easier to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the following permission in the AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yes I have, I have another activity which saves to a text file and that works with no errors. But for some reason this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file directory etc exists on the device in the first place that you are using

/appName/savedlocations  Good chance these do not exist. Wrong name for appName or savedLocations.  Check this using some file explorer program.  Tell us if it exists.  Print out the full path name of

```
      Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/appName/savedlocations
```

and see if it really exists.  Just download an app for file viewing or I think you can connect to the device via eclipse as well.  If you need more info on how to do it let us know.  But you should first check the actual error message and report this back.

Comment: I created the directory using "root.mkdirs();". I then checked on my sd card and the directory itself was created but the files were not. Also, I used a toast message to print the strings file and file2 and the paths seemed to be correct.

Answer (score -3):

don't invent your own serialization format. java already has that.

```
ArrayList<String> files = ...; // whatever

// write the object to a file

ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("filename.ser"));
out.writeObject(files);
out.close();

// read the object back

InputStream is = new FileInputStream("filename.ser"); 
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is); 
ArrayList<String> newFiles = = (ArrayList)ois.readObject(); 
ois.close();
```

Comment: I don't understand why your reading the object into an arraylist of file type. I declared an arraylist as string type. I don't want each object in the file saved as another file. Can you please explain this for me so I can better understand what your doing here.

Comment: @Jeffrey Blattman: He is not serializing. He is trying to write to and read back from txt files line by line. We do not know what he is doing with those text files later on so we cannot do generalizations. Also, he is using an ArrayList of Strings, not files.

Comment: @babatenor no, unless the post states specifics, we can make generalizations. if he needs them as flat text files, the psot should say that. and okay, change File to String and you are done.

Comment: @user1478764 1) whatever, replace File with String. 2) "i don't want each object ... saved as another file" this doesn't do that. it saves a list of strings to a file. unless you have other requirements to keep flat files, this is the most object-oriented solution. you have an object (a List<String>) and you want to persist it to a file, and restore it later. done.

Comment: If you read his code, you can easily understand that he is writing back to a txt file (and failing to do so). Also him trying to read back from a txt file justifies this...

Comment: @babatenor smart developers focus on solving a problem not a particular implementation. inventing a new file format is always a bad idea, even if it's a simple one. that's why things like serialization and Properties exist in java, so you don't do that.

Comment: Thank you baba tenor, you seem to understand what I am trying to do. I will try and run it on the emulator that way I can post the log files as some people have requested. Hopefully, then we can find a solution.